# How to validate Validate NCName in C++

Tags: c#, c++, xml

In .NET you have

[XmlConvert.VerifyNCName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.verifyncname%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[XmlConvert.IsNCNameChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.isncnamechar%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

etc to validate a **[NCName](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#NCName)**

How can one do the equivalent in C++ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/download.cgi) library from Apache, more specifically the [XMLChar1_1::isValidNCName](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classXMLChar1__1.html#b0c0aa3ecba045789e3f6404845c806e) method.

If you're using Visual Studio, you can also use C++/CLI, which will allow you to mix unmanaged C++ with managed C++, in which you'll be able to use the .NET functions.